# Bottom of page disappears after executing script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a page that will enable the user to enter their resume. I present them a standard html form which includes usual basic info (name, address, etc.). Then, for tertiary education and work experience, I present a single group of related  fields with an option to add more fields via a button that execute the scripts addTerciario() and addExp(), respectively.

The problem I have is that when I execute the scripts, I loose the bottom of the page (everything below the end of the span with id="experienciaspan"). This happens in chrome and edge (haven't tested other browsers).

I stripped all the fancy css and other javascript into a basic html document and it is still happening.

I put a console log to output the document's innerhtml, and it is all there, including the added fields and the bottom of the page, but it is not being rendered!

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong here?

Below is my html and javascript. Content is in Spanish, but it's pretty basic stuff so I hope you will have no problem following it.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Trabajá con nosostros</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</HEAD>
<body>
<p>Trabajá con nosotros</p>
            <hr/>
            <p> Completá este formulario con tus datos para incorporarte a nuestra base de datos de postulantes. Nos comunicaremos contigo cuando haya un puesto acorde a tu info.</p>
            <form class="curriculumform" name="formulario">
            <!-- This is where the basic info is entered -->
            <span id="terciariaspan">
            <p>Terciaria/universitaria:<select name="terciaria"><option value="completa">Completa</option><option value="parcial">Parcial</option><option value="sin">Ninguna</option></select> <span id="TerciariaGradoParcial" >Último año cursado:<input type="number" name="terciario_parcial_grado" min="1" max="7" value="1"/></span>
            <p>Carrera: <input name="carrera">
            <p>Comentario (opcional) <input name="terciaria_comentario" height="2"></p>
            </span>
            <hr/>
            <p><button type="button" onclick="addTerciario()">+ Agregar educación terciara/universitaria</button>
            <h3>Experiencia laboral</h3><p>(De más reciente a más antigua)</p>
            <p>¿Estás trabajando acualmente? <select name="trabajando"><option value="si">Sí</option><option value="no">No</option></select>
            <hr/>
            <span id="experienciaspan">
            <p>Empresa <input name="empresa">
            <p>Puesto <input name="puesto">
            <p>Desde <input type="date" name="expdesde"/> Hasta <input type="date" name="exphasta"/>
            <p> Referencia (opcional) <input name="referencia"/>
            </span>
            <hr/>
            <p><button type="button"  onclick="addExp();">+ Agregar experiencia</button>
        </form>
        <p>.</p>
</body>
<script>
            function addTerciario(){
                val1=Array.from(document.getElementsByName("terciaria"));
                val2=Array.from(document.getElementsByName("terciario_parcial_grado"));
                val3=Array.from(document.getElementsByName("terciaria_comentario"));
                val4=Array.from(document.getElementsByName("carrera"));
                var n=val4.length;
                var html="";
                for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
                    v1=val1[i].value;
                    v2=val2[i].value;
                    v3=val3[i].value;
                    v4=val4[i].value;
                    html+='<p>Terciaria/universitaria:<select name="terciaria" value="'+v1+'"><option value="completa">Completa</option><option value="parcial">Parcial</option><option value="sin">Ninguna</option></select> <span id="TerciariaGradoParcial" >Último año cursado:<input type="number" name="terciario_parcial_grado" value="'+v2+'" min="1" max="7" value="1"/></span><p>Carrera: <input name="carrera" value="'+v4+'"><p>Comentario (opcional) <input name="terciaria_comentario" value="'+v3+'" height="2"></p>';

                }
                html+='<p>Terciaria/universitaria:<select name="terciaria"><option value="completa">Completa</option><option value="parcial">Parcial</option><option value="sin">Ninguna</option></select> <span id="TerciariaGradoParcial" >Último año cursado:<input type="number" name="terciario_parcial_grado" min="1" max="7" value="1"/></span><p>Carrera: <input name="carrera" ><p>Comentario (opcional) <input name="terciaria_comentario" height="2"></p>';
                document.getElementById("experienciaspan").innerHTML="";
                document.getElementById("experienciaspan").innerHTML=html;
            }
            function addExp(){
                val1=Array.from(document.getElementsByName("empresa"));
                val2=Array.from(document.getElementsByName("puesto"));
                val3=Array.from(document.getElementsByName("expdesde"));
                val4=Array.from(document.getElementsByName("exphasta"));
                val5=Array.from(document.getElementsByName("referencia"));
                var n=val2.length;
                var html="";
                for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
                    v1=val1[i].value;
                    v2=val2[i].value;
                    v3=val3[i].value;
                    v4=val4[i].value;
                    v5=val5[i].value;

                    html+='<p>Empresa <input name="empresa" value="'+v1+'"></p><p>Puesto <input name="puesto" value="'+v2+'"></p><p>Desde <input type="date" value="'+v3+'" name="expdesde"/> Hasta <input type="date" value="'+v4+'" name="exphasta"/></p><p> Referencia (opcional) <input name="referencia" value="'+v5+'"/></p>';

                }
                html+='<p>Empresa <input name="empresa"></p><p>Puesto <input name="puesto"></p><p>Desde <input type="date" name="expdesde"/> Hasta <input type="date" name="exphasta"/></p><p> Referencia (opcional) <input name="referencia"/></p>';
                document.getElementById("experienciaspan").innerHTML="";
                document.getElementById("experienciaspan").innerHTML=html;
                console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
            }
        </script>
</html>
```

I expect that when executing the addExp() function, A new group of fields with names "empresa", "puesto", "expdesde", "exphasta" and "referencia" will appear within the span "experienciaspan", with any values entered previously by the user preserved.
This does happen, but has the side effect of making everything below said span to disappear.
What is completely weird is that this also happens when executing the script addTerciario(), which has nothing to do with the span "experienciaspan".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is all the unclosed p tags. Setting innerHTML removes the rest of the page because everything after the first unclosed p inside your span is considered to be inside the span. Here is the html with all the p tags closed:

```
<p>Trabajá con nosotros</p>
            <hr/>
            <p> Completá este formulario con tus datos para incorporarte a nuestra base de datos de postulantes. Nos comunicaremos contigo cuando haya un puesto acorde a tu info.</p>
            <form class="curriculumform" name="formulario">
            <!-- This is where the basic info is entered -->
            <span id="terciariaspan">
            <p>Terciaria/universitaria:<select name="terciaria"><option value="completa">Completa</option><option value="parcial">Parcial</option><option value="sin">Ninguna</option></select> <span id="TerciariaGradoParcial" >Último año cursado:<input type="number" name="terciario_parcial_grado" min="1" max="7" value="1"/></span></p>
            <p>Carrera: <input name="carrera"> </p>
            <p>Comentario (opcional) <input name="terciaria_comentario" height="2"></p>
            </span>
            <hr/>
            <p><button type="button" onclick="addTerciario()">+ Agregar educación terciara/universitaria</button> </p>
            <h3>Experiencia laboral</h3> <p>(De más reciente a más antigua)</p>
            <p>¿Estás trabajando acualmente? <select name="trabajando"><option value="si">Sí</option><option value="no">No</option></select> </p>
            <hr/>
            <span id="experienciaspan">
            <p>Empresa <input name="empresa"> </p>
            <p>Puesto <input name="puesto"> </p>
            <p>Desde <input type="date" name="expdesde"/> Hasta <input type="date" name="exphasta"/> </p>
            <p> Referencia (opcional) <input name="referencia"/> </p>
            </span>
            <hr/>
            <p><button type="button"  onclick="addExp();">+ Agregar experiencia</button> </p>
        </form>
        <p>.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! I really thought those closing tags were optional.